# I need to rewrite a URL to correct query string parameters

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have a URL that is like this:
https://www.example.com/msg/13243993939393/?param1=first&param2=second/param3=last

It needs to be corrected to this:
https://www.example.com/msg/13243993939393/?param1=first&param2=second&param3=last

I could enter it in the .htaccess file in my root, or (preferably) add an .htaccess in the folder /msg

Everything I've tried doesn't work. Any help would be greatly appreciated!!

Answer (score 0):

Is there no way to correct the URL at its source?

If you *must* work with it, do an external redirect with the corrected query string. Something like this:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ([^/]*)/([^/]*)
RewriteRule .* /$0?%1&%2 [L,R=301]
```

Test it's all okay before using the `=301` part, otherwise you'll have to empty your cache before each test. Use the sequence `%23` in your query (an encoded `#`) which will quickly show unescaped/double-escaped character issues.